# Is it possible to display value of App Service Config of Function App(Configuration) on Azure dashboard?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

As title says is it possible? Could not even find an option to pin app service config settings into dashboard.

Comment: why -1? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pin app service config settings into dashboard?

No, it is not possible to pin App service configuration settings to the azure dashboard.

[image]

You can add only resources or resource groups or any arm endpoint operations to the azure dashboard directly.